# c# marshaling output char* from c++ function

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I created a dll using C++ and I want to use it in C#
Here is the C++ function I want to use:

```
int get_value_of_field ( const int iObjectTag,
                         const char iAttName[],
                         char *oAttValue)
{
    int retcode = 0;
    char *AttValue = NULL;
    ITK (tc_custom_methods::get_value_of_field (iObjectTag, iAttName, &AttValue));
    if (retcode == 0) { sprintf(oAttValue, "%s", AttValue); }

    try { MEM_free(AttValue); }
    catch (exception e) { printf("MEM_free error\n%s\n", e.what()); }
    AttValue = NULL;
    return retcode;
}
```

I created this function in C#:

```
        [DllImport("tc_custom_caller.dll", EntryPoint = "get_value_of_field", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int get_value_of_field(int iObjectTag,
                                                     [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string iAttName,
                                                     StringBuilder oAttValue);

        /*!
         * \brief Get value of field of an object
         * \param[in]  iObjectTag Tag of the object
         * \param[in]  iAttName Attribute name
         * \param[out] oAttValue Attribute value
         */
        public static void Get_Value_Of_Field(int iObjectTag, string iAttName, out string oAttValue)
        {
            int retcode = 0;
            StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder();
            oAttValue = "";

            retcode = get_value_of_field(iObjectTag, iAttName, sbValue);
            if (retcode != 0) { throw new Exception("Error in get_value_of_field: " + Get_Error_Text(retcode)); }

            oAttValue = sbValue.ToString();
            sbValue = null;
        }
```

It works but after a lot of utilization of this function, the program crashes probably because of memory leak...

So could you tell me what is wrong with my code? Is there another way to manage the output of my C++ function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create your dll with c++/clr then you will have native .Net support build in. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes. You will probably end up with more stable code (no need for pinning memory for C++ to keep the garbage collector from moving stuff around while C++ is working on it)

Comment: Don't use ASCII strings in C++, especially if you want to use that string with *any* other language - in almost every other language strings are Unicode by default. In any case, the string types in C++ are `string`, `wstring`, `u16string`, `u8string`. Not `char*`, that's C and the difference matters

Comment: There are several serious bugs in the C++ code - using `MEM_free` instead of `delete`??? Which obviously crashes, hence that `try` to cover up the bug? `char *AttValue = NULL;` instead of an actual string. `sprintf` instead of `std::format`. Which doesn't make sense anyway - if `AttValue` is a string, what's the point of using `sprintf` to assign it to a new string?

Comment: You need to fix the broken C++ function and actually use C++ properly

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Concerning, c++/clr, as you can see, I'm not a C++ expert so I'm not sure I will be able to rewrite everything (the function I posted is just an example of the full dll I created; it's much larger)
Also, this dll use API suing char* as parameters. I'm not sure I will be capable of converting everything into string type...
Finally, I would be happy to fix the C++ function but I don't know how. @PanagiotisKanavos gives me some hint but I'm not sure how to use them... Could you show me an example?

Comment: @kor6k the problem isn't C++/CLR, this is simply bad C++ code. You need to learn to write C++ first. You put a lot of effort trying to cover up access violation errors - copy the output string with `sprintf` and then try to hide the deallocation error with `try`. Instead of a `char*` parameter *return a `std::string` or `std::wstring`. Instead of error codes, just let exceptions work. Your code already paid the cost of throwing an exception. `tc_custom_methods::get_value_of_field ` should return a string instead of modifying a buffer

Comment: If you read any of the `Effective C++` books and guidelines you'll find that most basic ones is to *not* use C constructs, *not* use char arrays when you really want strings, *not* to use `malloc` and `free`, *do* use exceptions instead of error codes. Use references where possible. Not pass raw pointers either but use one of the smart pointer classes that make it explicit who owns that pointer

Comment: I *strongly* suggest reading [Welcome back to C++ - Modern C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/welcome-back-to-cpp-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170). The changes there aren't new either, the guidelines against `char*` and `malloc` were published in the `Effective C++` book in 1992. That's 30 years ago

Comment: Set the StringBuilder.Capacity before the call.  Best to pass that value to the C++ code as well so it can safely copy the string without corrupting memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution:
here are my codes:

C# function (the same as before):

```
        [DllImport("tc_custom_caller.dll", EntryPoint = "get_value_of_field", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int get_value_of_field(int iObjectTag,
                                                     [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string iAttName,
                                                     StringBuilder oAttValue);

        /*!
         * \brief Get value of field of an object
         * \param[in]  iObjectTag Tag of the object
         * \param[in]  iAttName Attribute name
         * \param[out] oAttValue Attribute value
         */
        public static void Get_Value_Of_Field(int iObjectTag, string iAttName, out string oAttValue)
        {
            int retcode = 0;
            StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(4096);
            oAttValue = "";

            retcode = get_value_of_field(iObjectTag, iAttName, sbValue);
            if (retcode != 0) { throw new Exception("Error in get_value_of_field: " + Get_Error_Text(retcode)); }

            oAttValue = sbValue.ToString();
            sbValue = null;
        }
```

my C++ function get_value_of_field of the Wrapper is:

```
int get_value_of_field ( const int iObjectTag,
                         const char iAttName[],
                         char *oAttValue)
{
    int retcode = 0;
    string AttValue;
    ITK (tc_custom_methods::get_value_of_field (iObjectTag, iAttName, AttValue));
    strcpy(oAttValue, AttValue.c_str());
    return retcode;
}
```

and I changed the tc_custom_methods::get_value_of_field like this:

```
    // Get value of field of an object
    int tc_custom_methods::get_value_of_field (const int iObjectTag,
                                               const char iAttName[],
                                               string &oAttValue)
    {
        // do some stuff ...
        return 0;
    }
```

I think it will be better like this. If you see something wrong with this code, please tell me!